# Single Select Checkbox Using JSF

Tags: jsf, jsf-2

I am creating registration form in JSF and I have field as Active, Inactive where I need to use check boxes and these checkboxes should be SINGLE SELECT ONLY. (Note: I can use radio button and solve the problem, however due to some problem I have to use check boxes).

Please suggest me how to get this done?

Thanks in advance...

Comment: *"however due to some problem"* which problem? Why not just solve that so that you can just use radio buttons instead of hacking around with checkboxes? Also, please explicitly mention which JSF version you're using. You've both JSF 1.2 and 2.0 tags on the question. This is confusing. You should have only one of them. Which JSF version are you using?

Comment: I'm using JSF 2.0..

Actually I had to create a program where I was asked to use check boxes only and NOT radio buttons... hence I was looking for check box solution...

Comment: Please remove the incorrect JSF 1.2 tag. As to checkbox vs radiobutton, well the problem is clearly just the ignorance of the customer/manager. You as developer has just to explain the customer that checkboxes are supposed for multiple selections and radio buttons for single selections.

Comment: I suggested the same, however they STRICTLY need checkboxes... :(

that is mine bad luck...

Comment: removed incorrect tag...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think what you need is `<h:selectBooleanCheckbox>`. The value binded to this component can only be either true (Active) or false (Inactive). It will be something like the following:

```
<h:selectBooleanCheckbox id="active" value="#{mrBean.active}" >
   <f:ajax render="inactive" listener="#{mrBean.onActiveStatusChange}" />
</h:selectBooleanCheckbox>
<h:selectBooleanCheckbox id="inactive" value="#{mrBean.inactive}" >
   <f:ajax render="active" listener="#{mrBean.onInactiveStatusChange}" />
</h:selectBooleanCheckbox>

@ManagedBean
@RequestScoped
public class MrBean {
   private boolean active;
   private boolean inactive;

   @PostConstruct
   public void prepareMrBean() {
      this.active = true;
   }

   public void onActiveStatusChange() {
      if (active) inactive = false;
   }

   public void onInactiveStatusChange() {
      if (inactive) active = false;
   }
}
```