# Taking Project Online From Localhost

Tags: web-applications, jsf-2, localhost

I have created **Web Application** using JSF 2.0, MySQL & Netbeans.

This application works perfectly on localhost. Now I want to take this project online.

Steps that I would need to follow would be appreciated.

I believe I would need to use the webhosting sites like [www.hostgator.com](http://www.hostgator.com) or other.

Answer (score 1):

Hmmm... I think the steps should be something like this:

1. Get a VPS, private server or something else from hosting companies like Oxxus.
2. Ask the service provider to install GlassFish & MySQL on the "machine" that you got from step 1. You can also do it yourself by downloading GlassFish [here](http://glassfish.java.net/downloads/3.1.2-final.html) and simply extract the zip file[1].
3. Set up the Application server just like how you did it locally (with changes to values where appropriate).
4. Build your project.
5. Launch GlassFish Admin panel at http://yoursite.com:4848.
6. Click "Applications" on the left tree and choose "Deploy...".
7. Upload the `.ear` file in your project' `dist` folder.
8. Accept this answer if everything works fine :)).

Comment: I have account with http://www.hostgator.com I believe for step 1, it would work. Right? I shall try this and get back to you incase of any queries. Can I get your email id so that I can ask for any queries? My email id is there in my profile. Thanks a ton for help. I remember you had helped me earlier [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8709112/single-select-checkbox-using-jsf)

Comment: Also how should I setup MySQL database? Because for locahost, I was using local mysql data. I read some points [here](http://www.codemyownroad.com/13-steps-to-deploy-wordpress-from-your-localhost-to-a-live-web-server/). Let me know if they are helpful.

Comment: hmmmm.... I think you should ask the hosting provider's admins to help you install [Webmin](http://www.webmin.com/) and [MySQL module](http://www.webmin.com/standard.html). After that, it should be very straight-forward. You just need to login as an admin to create a MySQL user account and a database. When you create the JDBC connection to MySQL database, you just need to fill in your server address, etc. and it's done. My email is in my profile too :).

Answer (score 0):

Well, yes, the first step would be to find a host that offers the technologies you use (JSF etc.) but what happens after that is heavily dependent on the individual host and what they offer in the way of management (CPanel, FTP, phpMyAdmin etc.) so it's probably a question for the host's support or here once you've got an account with one.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest for starters would be moving the application to the cloud.

Try Amazon Elastic Beanstalk, [link](http://aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/).

If you are first time user, you can qualify for the free tier where you can use micro instances for free up to an year.

You can also try OpenShift from Red Hat. This is a nice article on how to deploy your application to rhcloud in 5 minutes.

- [How To Push Java EE 6 Applications To The Cloud In 5 Minutes](http://www.adam-bien.com/roller/abien/entry/how_to_push_java_ee)