# uncheck a checkbox when another checkbox is checked in jsf

Tags: jsf, jsf-2, checkbox, primefaces

I have a scenario, that if i check one check box the other should be unchecked.

I am using JSF.

**My Code:**

```
 <p:dataTable>
      <p:column headerText="PAID">
            <p:selectBooleanCheckbox value="#{bean.paid}" />
      </p:column>
      <p:column headerText="NOT PAID">
            <p:selectBooleanCheckbox value="#{bean.notPaid}"/>
       </p:column>
 </p:dataTable>
```

**Clear View:**

[image]

How can i achieve this!

Comment: This UI is normally achieved with radio buttons. Why are you using checkboxes?

Comment: Yes, it can be done with Radio Buttons but i need a Checkbox View.as it can be done with jquery, i'm in search that whether we can have the same with JSF also

Comment: Yes, certainly it's possible. Just wondering because of the non-intuitive UI and I'm not a fan of recommending poor approaches :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[@Mr.J4mes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8709112/single-select-checkbox-using-jsf) had worked .

I tried with the same approach but with `<p:selectBooleanCheckbox>`.

**Code**

```
<p:column id="paid" headerText="Paid">
    <p:selectBooleanCheckbox id="paidCheckBox" value="#{bean.paid}">
       <p:ajax update="notPaidCheckBox" listener="#{bean.onPaidStatusChange}" />
    </p:selectBooleanCheckbox>
</p:column>
<p:column id="notPaid" headerText="NotPaid">
    <p:selectBooleanCheckbox id="notPaidCheckBox" value="#{bean.notPaid}">
        <p:ajax update="paidCheckBox" listener="#{bean.onNotPaidStatusChange}" />
    </p:selectBooleanCheckbox>
</p:column>

@ManagedBean(name="bean")
@SessionScoped
public class Bean {
   private boolean paid;
   private boolean notpaid;

   @PostConstruct
   public void Bean() {
      this.paid= true;
   }

   public void onPaidStatusChange() {
      if (paid) notpaid= false;
   }

   public void onNotPaidStatusChange() {
      if (notpaid) paid= false;
   }
}
```

This worked Fine. `Thanks for Mr.J4mes approach ;-)`