# Check or uncheck selectBooleanCheckBox by checking another

Tags: jsf

I have a , situation:
In a `JSF` page i have some `selectBooleanCheckbox`. And i needed that, when i check one of them, some others were unchecked. I'm working on this to add or remove columns from a `JasperReports` report, just to explain why do i need that to work.

Is it possible? If yes, i would like some help to achieve that, thanks.

xhtml:

```
                    <h:selectBooleanCheckbox value="#{simpleReport.colunaId}" />
                    <h:outputText escape="false" value="Cód." />
                    <h:selectBooleanCheckbox value="#{simpleReport.colunaCliente}" />
                    <h:outputText escape="false" value="Cliente" />
                    <h:selectBooleanCheckbox value="#{simpleReport.colunaCondutor}" />
                    <h:outputText escape="false" value="Condutor" />
                    <h:selectBooleanCheckbox
                        value="#{simpleReport.colunaCondicaoTempo}" />
                    <h:outputText escape="false" value="Cond. Tempo" />
                    <h:selectBooleanCheckbox value="#{simpleReport.colunaOcorrencia}" />
                    <h:outputText escape="false" value="Ocorrência" />
                    <h:selectBooleanCheckbox value="#{simpleReport.colunaStatus}" />
                    <h:outputText escape="false" value="Status" />
                    <h:selectBooleanCheckbox value="#{simpleReport.colunaPeriodo}" />
                    <h:outputText escape="false" value="Período" />
                    <h:selectBooleanCheckbox value="#{simpleReport.colunaSoma}" />
                    <h:outputText escape="false" value="Soma" />
                    <h:selectBooleanCheckbox value="#{simpleReport.colunaQtdCli}" />
                    <h:outputText escape="false" value="QtdCli" />
                    <h:selectBooleanCheckbox value="#{simpleReport.groupByCLiente}" />
                    <h:outputText escape="false" value="Group" />
```

Bean

```
boolean colunaId = false, colunaCliente = false, colunaCondutor = false, colunaPeriodo = false,
        colunaCondicaoTempo = false, colunaStatus = false, colunaOcorrencia = false, colunaSoma = false,
        colunaQtdCond = false, colunaQtdCli = false;

boolean groupByCLiente = false, groupByCondutor = false;
```

I have found this post : [Single Select Checkbox Using JSF](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8709112/single-select-checkbox-using-jsf) but it is not the very same case, and i was not able to achieve what i need yet.

For example, if i check "group" it sould uncheck "Ocorrencia" and "Status".
[image]

Comment: Is there a reason why you tagged the question with `primefaces` but only using plain jsf tags? If you are using PrimeFaces you may make use of its client side API, basically just check/ununcheck the checkboxes via JavaScript

Comment: I believe it was  just my mistake on the tag.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should add a `<p:ajax` child to the checkboxes who should effect others where you `update` the respective checkboxes to be affected and add a `listener` method which resets the respective values of the checkboxes to be affected in your view model. Similar to

## page.xhtml

```
<!-- Should be reset if "2" is selected -->
<p:selectBooleanCheckbox id="1" value="#{view.value1}"/> 

<p:selectBooleanCheckbox id="2" value="#{view.value2}">
    <p:ajax update="1" listener="#{view.resetValue1}"/>
</p:selectBooleanCheckbox>
```

## View.java

```
public void resetValue1() {
    this.value1 = false;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, i'll try to make it work here.

Comment: It's working but, how can i do to define more than one `selectBooleanCheckbox`to be updated based on the selectedone? Like (if i could, but i believe i can't) <p:ajax update="1,2,3..."